# How get divs count in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, count

I used this jquery each function and iterated my json data with it....

```
$.each(data.Results, function() {
   divs += '<div class="resultsdiv"><br />
  <span style="display: inline-block;width:150px;" class="resultName">'
 + this.Mat_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:10px;">
 Measurement&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' 
 + this.Mes_Name + '</span>&nbsp;<a href="/Materials/Delete/' + this.Id + '">
Delete</a>&nbsp;<a href="/Materials/Details/' + this.Id + '">Details</a>&nbsp;
<a href="/Materials/Edit/' + this.Id + '">Edit</a></div>';
   });
```

`alert(divs.length);` doesnt seem to get the count.... Any suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`divs` is a string, so `divs.length` would return the length of that string.  You need to convert it into a DOM node, select the divs, and get the count:

```
$('div', '<wrapper>' + divs + '</wrapper>').length;
```

Alternatively, in the code you provided you could just get the length of the data.Results array:

```
data.Results.length;
```

Comment: If you want to get count of divs with specific id or class, or divs within some specific div, then you can use the relevant selector as well `var num = $(".parent-div-class div.child-div-class").length; alert(num);`